# OSQA in a rails 3 application?

Tags: django, ruby-on-rails-3, osqa

I would like to integrate a Q&A system or a forum with my rails 3 application. OSQA looks really good and seems to be exactly what I am looking for. Unfortunately it is in python and django.
I am a newbie and I am not sure if such an application can be integrated with rails 3, I appreciate your comments on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should manually connect sessions and authentication systems, it's good to make an API for connection.

Anyway, it's not "1-click task" so if you have no experience with Python, it's better to find something similar (maybe less feature-rich) for Rails. At least, you can always extend it if you need.

Comment: Shapado offers similar functionality and it's a ruby gem. I dislike the user interface. I guess it is more convenient if I use shapado but change the UI...